# Разве Hashmap сортируется автоматичски?

Tags: java, java-hashmap

Написал тестовый код, чтоб объяснить проблему.

```
mport java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(6,"A");
        map.put(3,"B");
        map.put(2,"C");
        map.put(7,"D");
        map.put(1,"E");

        for (Object obj :
                map.entrySet()) {
            Map.Entry <Integer, String> pair = (Map.Entry <Integer, String>) obj;
            System.out.println(pair.getKey()+" "+pair.getValue());
        }
    }
}

Консоль: 
1 E
2 C
3 B
6 A
7 D
```

Почему HashMap автоматически сортирует карты по ключу? Ведь насколько я знаю, он не должен этого делать.....

Comment: Насколько я помyю мапа "сортирует" по хэшу ключа, а какой хэш integer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Хэш целого числа - это само значения этого числа, поэтому по бакетам числа распределятся последовательно и, соответственно, выведены тоже будут последовательно.

Comment: ещё уточнение, последовательно по модулю 16

Comment: да каждые 16, количеству изначальных корзинок, индекс 16 будет первым если он добавлен последним , также как и 32 и тд

Comment: Спасибо!!!! Разобрался наконец-то!!!